# Java Integer Overflow and why Integer.MAX_VALUE / 10?

Tags: java, integer, overflow

This is code from Leetcode solution. So I don't understand the if condition, why Integer.MAX_VALUE has to be divided by 10 (Interger.MAX_VALUE / 10) ?

Thank You!

```
class Solution {
    public int reverse(int x) {
        int rev = 0;
        while (x != 0) {
            int pop = x % 10;
            x /= 10;
            if (rev > Integer.MAX_VALUE/10 || (rev == Integer.MAX_VALUE / 10 && pop > 7)) return 0;
            if (rev < Integer.MIN_VALUE/10 || (rev == Integer.MIN_VALUE / 10 && pop < -8)) return 0;
            rev = rev * 10 + pop;
        }
        return rev;
    }
}
```

Comment: Prevents overflow.

Comment: What’s the question for which this code was written?

Answer (score 4):

The `reverse(int x)` function reverses the decimal digits of `x`. For example, if `x = 102`, it returns `201`, and if `x = -102`, it returns `-201`.

When the reverse of `x` is computed, it is stored in `rev`. For example, for `x = 102`, `rev` takes the successive values `2`, `20`, `201`.

At each iteration, `rev` is multiplied by `10`, and one digit is added to it. Of course, `rev` cannot be greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (`2147483647`). So, before multiplying `rev` by `10`, we check whether multiplying it by `10` and adding `pop` would make it greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

We first check whether `rev` is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE / 10` (`214748364`). If it is greater, the reverse integer does not exist. If not, then `rev` is less than or equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE / 10`. If it is less than `Integer.MAX_VALUE / 10`, then even if we multiply it by `10`, we can add any digit (`pop`) to it, and we will not exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. However, if it is equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE / 10`, then we must that make sure that `pop` is not `> 7` (`2147483647 - 214748364 * 10`) because we would otherwise exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

The same reasoning applies to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (`2147483648`).

Comment: @pkim Did that answer your question?

Comment: It sure did! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight forward. Its mainly added so that you don't hit integer memory out of bound exception.

```
Line 1:   rev == Integer.MAX_VALUE / 10
Line 2:  rev = rev * 10 + pop;
```

Let's assume the above case is true for some value.  `Line 1 means that 10*rev = Integer.MAX_VALUE.` Line 2: rev is an integer. if as per line 1, we have encountered a case where `rev = Integer.MAX_VALUE,` if we add a pop on top of it, we would encounter integer memory out of bound exception. To avoid that, Line 1 is added.  Sample test case to make sure Line 1 is executed is `"Pass Integer.MAX_VALUE" as an input to reverse() function.`